# Is it possible to use Android Emulator to pass identity confirmation via Android Device?

Tags: google-account, 9.0-pie, 2fa

My google account is requiring I [confirm my identity using an Android device](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6046815?hl=en), but I have no android devices.  I had logged in with one over 4 years ago, but no longer have any (switched to IOS for work).  I do have some Windows VMs and thought to possibly run the Android Emulator to simulate an Android device, but had thought from past experience that Google Play Services wouldn't run through the emulator, so likely many of these types of features wouldn't work.

Thoughts on how to get past it without having to buy a $50 TracPhone, which just seems like simple extortion?  I see no google-groups or other means of contacting google-account-services support.

Comment: I am un-sure if it would work but this is a Google play system image with an android emulator: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/04/google-play-system-images-android.html?m=1

Answer (score 1):

***UPDATE***
I likely won't install the ADK and Emulator as I was able to resolve the issue without it.  The solution to the problem was to acknowledge all recent logins into my account.  The reason it wanted extra verification was that I had already passed 2FA, but since that login was not acknowledged (via my recover email), it took all 2FA as "tainted".  This is why it wouldn't allow me to verify via recovery phone number.  To solve this issue, this is the procedure I did.

1. Log into the account
2. Click on the user icon on the top right of GMail and select [***Google Account***](https://myaccount.google.com/)
3. From the Account page click [***Security***](https://myaccount.google.com/security)
4. Look for a "[***Secure Account***](https://myaccount.google.com/security-checkup)" link under first main heading for Security.  You may see an open lock with an exclamation mark.
5. Try to resolve all the name security issues listed.

Alternatively you may likely just look for security alerts listed in your "Recovery Email" account